# Multiple Sns plot distort in flask using savefig and sendfile

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, graph

I have a html file that displays the images sent from the flask backend.

```html
<body>
    
    <h3> Count plot of data according to Lead origin.</h3>

    <img src = "/graph_visualization/" alt = "graph it is" height = "300" width = "300">

    <h3> Count plot of data according to cities</h3>

    <img src = "/graph_visualization2/" alt = "graph it is" height = "300" width = "300">

    <h3> Count plot of data according to Countries</h3>

    <img src = "/graph_visualization3/" alt = "graph it is" height = "300" width = "300">

</body>
```

The three plots are sent as a png file from multiple functions in flask backend as below:

```
@app.route('/graph_visualization/')
def graph_visualization():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\export.csv')
    sns.countplot(x="Lead Origin", hue="Converted", data=df)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    img = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png', cache_timeout=-1)


@app.route('/graph_visualization2/')
def graph_visualization2():
    fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\export.csv')
    sns.countplot(x="Cities", hue="Converted", data=df)
    xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.tight_layout()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig1)
    img1 = BytesIO()
    fig1.savefig(img1, format='png')
    img1.seek(0)

    return send_file(img1, mimetype='image/png', cache_timeout=-1)


@app.route('/graph_visualization3/')
def graph_visualization3():
    fig2, ax = plt.subplots()
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\export.csv')
    sns.barplot(x="Countries", y="Converted", data=df)
    xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('Converted')
    plt.xlabel('Countries')
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig2)
    img2 = BytesIO()
    fig2.savefig(img2, formar='png')
    img2.seek(0)

    return send_file(img2, mimetype='image/png', cache_timeout=-1)
```

[image: The output is like this:]

**Note: Individual graph shows when i comment any two functions and only keep one. The problem is when i uncomment all of them.**

I have tried following methods:

1. Changing the figurename and image name in each functions.
2. `plt.clf()` below `fig.savefig()`
3. `ax.clear()` below `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
4. Run in Incognito mode.

**Note: I don't want to make multiple subplots.**

Please let me know if my approach to the problem is incorrect.